# Finding consecutive counts of nan in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with missing values. I want to find the number of consecutive missing values along with their counts. Below is the sample data and sample result that I expect

```
Sample data

Timestamp            X
2018-01-02 00:00:00  6
2018-01-02 00:05:00  6
2018-01-02 00:10:00  4
2018-01-02 00:15:00  nan
2018-01-02 00:20:00  nan
2018-01-02 00:25:00  3
2018-01-02 00:30:00  4
2018-01-02 00:35:00  nan
2018-01-02 00:40:00  nan
2018-01-02 00:45:00  nan
2018-01-02 00:50:00  nan
2018-01-02 00:55:00  nan
2018-01-02 01:00:00  nan
2018-01-02 01:05:00  2
2018-01-02 01:10:00  4
2018-01-02 01:15:00  6
2018-01-02 01:20:00  6
2018-01-02 01:25:00  nan
2018-01-02 01:30:00  nan
2018-01-02 01:35:00  6
2018-01-02 01:40:00  nan
2018-01-02 01:45:00  nan
2018-01-02 01:50:00  6
2018-01-02 01:55:00  6
2018-01-02 02:00:00  nan
2018-01-02 02:05:00  nan
2018-01-02 02:10:00  nan
2018-01-02 02:15:00  3
2018-01-02 02:20:00  4
```

Expected result

```
Consecutive missing 
values range                Cases
0-2                          3
3-5                          1
6 and above                  1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying consecutive NaN's with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007830/identifying-consecutive-nans-with-pandas)

Comment: @ Chris Thanks for your suggestion. However, the results that I am expecting is different from the result that you have suggested ? Suggest if you think otherwise ?

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use solution from [`Identifying consecutive NaN's with pandas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007830/identifying-consecutive-nans-with-pandas), then filter out `0` values and use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for bins, last count values by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = df.X.isna().groupby(df.X.notna().cumsum()).sum()
s = s[s!=0]

b = pd.cut(s, bins=[0, 2, 5, np.inf], labels=['0-2','3-5','6 and above'])
out = b.groupby(b).size().reset_index(name='Cases')
print (out)
             X  Cases
0          0-2      3
1          3-5      1
2  6 and above      1
```