# How to convert monthy data to nan based on a condition?

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
       CODE      DATE     TMAX  TMIN   PP
0      000130 1991-01-01  32.6  23.4  0.0
1      000130 1991-01-02  31.2  22.4  0.0
2      000130 1991-01-03  32.0   NaN  0.0
3      000130 1991-01-04  32.2  23.0  0.0
4      000130 1991-01-05  30.5  22.0  0.0
      ...        ...   ...   ...  ...
10865  000130 2020-12-31   NaN   NaN  NaN
10866  000132 1991-01-01  35.2   NaN  0.0
10867  000132 1991-01-02  34.6   NaN  0.0
10868  000132 1991-01-03  35.8   NaN  0.0
10869  000132 1991-01-04  34.8   NaN  0.0
```

I want to convert monthly data to NaN only if there is 5 or more consecutive NaN values in a month.

For example: If January 1991 have 5 consecutive or more NaN values in column TMAX, all January 1991 values of column TMAX must be converted to NaN. Same with every month in every year. I need to do this by CODE (Every CODE values has TMAX data in January 1991, February 1991, ... December 2020). So i'm thinking in use `df.groupby['CODE']` first. There are 371 codes.

For PP column i need to convert monthly data to NaN only if there is 3 or more NON consecutive NaN values in a month. For example: If January 1991 have 3 NON consecutive NaN values in column PP, all January 1991 values of column TMAX must be converted to NaN. Same with every month in every year. I also need to do this by CODE.

I'm begginer in python so i will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [identifying consecutive NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007830/identifying-consecutive-nans-with-pandas)
- a reasonable amount of code to generate a test data set
- define function to be called in `transform()`
- `groupby()` **CODE**, **year** & **month** calling function
- **n** is a parameter so can be used for different consecutive runs

```
# contruct a CODE / DATE dataframe
df = (pd.DataFrame([f"{i:08d}" for i in range(3)], columns=["CODE"]).assign(foo=1)
 .merge(pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("01-Jan-1991", "01-Jan-1993"), columns=["DATE"]).assign(foo=1), on="foo")
 .drop(columns="foo")
)


# add a column that has NaNs in it, some will consequetive...
A = np.random.uniform(20,30, len(df))
A.ravel()[np.random.choice(A.size, A.size//3, replace=False)] = np.nan
df["TMIN"] = A

# function that will return NaN if more than n consecutive NaNs
def consecutivenan(d, n=5):
    if d.isnull().astype(int).groupby(d.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()).sum().ge(n).any():
        return np.nan 
    else:
        return d

df["TMIN_C"] = df.groupby(["CODE", df.DATE.dt.year, df.DATE.dt.month], as_index=False)["TMIN"].transform(consecutivenan, n=5)

# demo it's worked
i = df.loc[~df.TMIN.isna() & df.TMIN.ne(df.TMIN_C)].index[0]
df.loc[i-2:i+28]
```

#### output

There are 5 consecutive **NaN** values so whole month has been set to **NaN**

|  | CODE | DATE | TMIN | TMIN_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 271 | 00000000 | 1991-09-29 00:00:00 | 28.1745 | 28.1745 |
| 272 | 00000000 | 1991-09-30 00:00:00 | 21.1691 | 21.1691 |
| 273 | 00000000 | 1991-10-01 00:00:00 | 28.7848 | nan |
| 274 | 00000000 | 1991-10-02 00:00:00 | 22.2346 | nan |
| 275 | 00000000 | 1991-10-03 00:00:00 | 22.306 | nan |
| 276 | 00000000 | 1991-10-04 00:00:00 | 21.5774 | nan |
| 277 | 00000000 | 1991-10-05 00:00:00 | 23.8348 | nan |
| 278 | 00000000 | 1991-10-06 00:00:00 | 21.4416 | nan |
| 279 | 00000000 | 1991-10-07 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 280 | 00000000 | 1991-10-08 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 281 | 00000000 | 1991-10-09 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 282 | 00000000 | 1991-10-10 00:00:00 | 27.3833 | nan |
| 283 | 00000000 | 1991-10-11 00:00:00 | 27.2125 | nan |
| 284 | 00000000 | 1991-10-12 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 285 | 00000000 | 1991-10-13 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 286 | 00000000 | 1991-10-14 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 287 | 00000000 | 1991-10-15 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 288 | 00000000 | 1991-10-16 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 289 | 00000000 | 1991-10-17 00:00:00 | 24.8782 | nan |
| 290 | 00000000 | 1991-10-18 00:00:00 | 29.7879 | nan |
| 291 | 00000000 | 1991-10-19 00:00:00 | 27.0532 | nan |
| 292 | 00000000 | 1991-10-20 00:00:00 | 21.3854 | nan |
| 293 | 00000000 | 1991-10-21 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 294 | 00000000 | 1991-10-22 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 295 | 00000000 | 1991-10-23 00:00:00 | 23.6399 | nan |
| 296 | 00000000 | 1991-10-24 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 297 | 00000000 | 1991-10-25 00:00:00 | 24.7265 | nan |
| 298 | 00000000 | 1991-10-26 00:00:00 | 20.2296 | nan |
| 299 | 00000000 | 1991-10-27 00:00:00 | 22.0885 | nan |
| 300 | 00000000 | 1991-10-28 00:00:00 | 27.3212 | nan |
| 301 | 00000000 | 1991-10-29 00:00:00 | nan | nan |