# How to interpolate missing values in Pandas depending upon various conditional approaches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one shown below:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1':[1.1, 2.2, 3.5, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 6.2, 7.9, 8.3, 9.6, 10.7, np.NaN, np.NaN, 11.1, 13.2, 14.7, np.NaN, 15.6, 18.3],
'Var2':[3.1, 6.2, 2.1, 3.6, np.NaN, 6.2, 13.2, 14.7, 7.9, 8.1, np.NaN, 9.2, 10.3, np.NaN, np.NaN,13.5, 14.2]})
```

For NANs I want to interpolate the missing data. And *my* strategy for such interpolation is that:

1. when there is only a single NA, use immediately before and after values, take their MEAN and replace NA with that MEAN
2. When there are two consecutive NAs, replace both with df['varX'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)
3. when there are more than two consecutive NAs, replace NAs with df['varX'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=3/2)

I thought on this: How can it be done?

I found this post a bit helpful, but it is not the one which could help me:
*[Identifying consecutive NaNs with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007830/identifying-consecutive-nans-with-pandas)*

Comment: `df['varX'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=3/2)` is correct? `NotImplementedError: 1.5 is unsupported: Use fitpack routines for other types.`

Comment: it may not be correct, i am just making a guess here. instead of 2 I was thinking if i could use 1.5 or 2.5 like polynomial? if not then we can think of an alternative.

Comment: ya, for me it return error, `order` has to be integer

Comment: understood! thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Var1':[1.1, 2.2, 3.5, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 6.2, 7.9, 8.3, 9.6, 10.7, np.NaN, np.NaN, 11.1, 13.2, 14.7, np.NaN],
'Var2':[3.1, 6.2, 2.1, 3.6, np.NaN, 6.2, 13.2, 14.7, 7.9, 8.1, np.NaN, 9.2, 10.3, np.NaN, np.NaN,13.5, 14.2]})
```

---

```
#count consecutive NaNs
f = lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts())
df1 = df.notna().cumsum().where(df.isna()).apply(f)
print (df1)
    Var1  Var2
0    NaN   NaN
1    NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN
3    3.0   NaN
4    3.0   1.0
5    3.0   NaN
6    NaN   NaN
7    NaN   NaN
8    NaN   NaN
9    NaN   NaN
10   NaN   1.0
11   2.0   NaN
12   2.0   NaN
13   NaN   2.0
14   NaN   2.0
15   NaN   NaN
16   1.0   NaN
```

---

```
#compare
m1 = df1.eq(1)
m2 = df1.eq(2)
m3 = df1.gt(2)

#interplations
df11 = df.ffill().add(df.bfill()).div(2)
#if need last/first NaNs replace by previous/last divide 2
#df11 = df.ffill().add(df.bfill(), fill_value=0).div(2)
df22 = df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)

#order need int
df33 = df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=3)

#set values by np.select
arr = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [df11, df22, df33], default=df)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print (df)
         Var1       Var2
0    1.100000   3.100000
1    2.200000   6.200000
2    3.500000   2.100000
3    4.175679   3.600000
4    4.492391   4.900000
5    4.987908   6.200000
6    6.200000  13.200000
7    7.900000  14.700000
8    8.300000   7.900000
9    9.600000   8.100000
10  10.700000   8.650000
11  10.857431   9.200000
12  10.323495  10.300000
13  11.100000  11.467171
14  13.200000  12.581168
15  14.700000  13.500000
16        NaN  14.200000
```

---

```
#if need last/first replace by previus 3 values
s1 = df.tail(3).mean().rename(df.index[-1])
s2 = df.head(3).mean().rename(df.index[0])

df = df.fillna(s1).fillna(s2)
print (df)
         Var1       Var2
0    1.100000   3.100000
1    2.200000   6.200000
2    3.500000   2.100000
3    4.175679   3.600000
4    4.492391   4.900000
5    4.987908   6.200000
6    6.200000  13.200000
7    7.900000  14.700000
8    8.300000   7.900000
9    9.600000   8.100000
10  10.700000   8.650000
11  10.857431   9.200000
12  10.323495  10.300000
13  11.100000  11.467171
14  13.200000  12.581168
15  14.700000  13.500000
16  13.950000  14.200000
```

Comment: wow! i am just trying to understand what you did :-) i think last NA should be interpolated using last three values. that would be better. no worries, let me try that, thank you for providing a headstart.

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque - Added to answer. Only need unique index, because last `fillna` match by last and first `df.index` values